# Oleh Regel Today

Tags: eretz-yisrael, mitzvah, beis-hamikdash, chagim-holidays

Is there a Mitzvah to be Oleh Regel in today's days (meaning when there is no Beis Hamikdash)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a little pamphlet of *t'shuvos*/analyses by Rav Mirsky that basically concludes that there is, especially fulfillable by feasting and dancing. I will try to locate, quote, and cite it.

Update: See *Sha'arei T'shuva* [529:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14165&st=&pgnum=305) (last one in volume 5) and the sources he cites for related information.

Comment: Is there maybe a PDF?

Comment: WAF rabbi mirsky of YCT?
This One

http://www.yctorah.org/content/view/153/54/

Answer (score 1):

See [this lecture by Rabbi Rapp](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/723111).

If I recall correctly, the basic obligation is not there, but many consider it a meritorious act to make it to Jerusalem or the Kotel for the holidays anyhow.

(I think he was quoting Tzitz Eliezer and -- yibadel l'chaim -- R' Ovadya Yosef).

Comment: I know a talmid chacham (he learned in Kaminetz in Europe- still alive) who would not go to the Kosel on the regalim so as not to violate v'lo yeraeh...reikam.

Comment: But surely that applies only to entering at least Machaneh Leviyah (the Har Habayis), if not Machaneh Shechinah (the Azarah)? And the Kosel is outside both of those.

Comment: Ydk wats funnier is Rav Eliyashiv goes to Shake Lulav on Purpose so he could have a Meain of the doraisa of SHaking Lulav. And its recorded That Saddiah Gaon used to be Oleh Regel in His time and walk around the Har Habayis